# JavaFX Custom Font

Tags: css, javafx, fonts, font-face

How to set a custom font to JavaFX (Java 17, OpenJFX)? I tried copying files to the resources/fonts folder and importing them via @font-face in CSS. It didn't work. Also tried @import - no use.

Answer (score 3):

After searching the internet for hours, finally resolved how to set the custom font in JavaFX and use it comfortably within the CSS.

The CSS File looks like this:

```
@font-face
{
    -fx-font-family: "Quicksand Light";
    src: url("../fonts/Quicksand-Light.ttf");
}


@font-face
{
    -fx-font-family: "Quicksand Regular";
    src: url("../fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf");
}

@font-face
{
    -fx-font-family: "Quicksand Medium";
    src: url("../fonts/Quicksand-Medium.ttf");
}

@font-face
{
    -fx-font-family: "Quicksand Semi-bold";
    src: url("../fonts/Quicksand-SemiBold.ttf");
}

@font-face
{
    -fx-font-family: "Quicksand Bold";
    src: url("../fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf");
}

.light
{
    -fx-font-family: "Quicksand Light";
}

.regular
{
    -fx-font-family: "Quicksand Regular";
}

.medium
{
    -fx-font-family: "Quicksand Medium";
}

.semi
{
    -fx-font-family: "Quicksand Semi-bold";
}

.bold
{
    -fx-font-family: "Quicksand Bold";
}
```

Now, in your java class you can set the styles accordingly as below:

```
    Label lblThin = new Label("Light");
    lblThin.getStyleClass().add("light");

    Label lblRegular = new Label("Regular");
    lblRegular.getStyleClass().add("regular");

    Label lblMedium = new Label("Medium");
    lblMedium.getStyleClass().add("medium");

    Label lblSemiBold = new Label("Semi Bold");
    lblSemiBold.getStyleClass().add("semi");

    Label lblBold = new Label("Bold");
    lblBold.getStyleClass().add("bold");
```

**Two main things to note:**

1. The font name should be exactly as per the font file and in double
   quotes
2. The original filename of the font should be maintained in
   your resources

**Attaching the resources/fonts photo to make it easy to understand:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

I hope this saves someone's time.

Comment: Note this is described in the [JavaFX CSS documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Comment: legend. others didn't work at all